# Why is Material-UI not allowing for custom transition here?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm using Material-UI v4 to create a custom transition on a 'Snackbar'. The Transition works as default, but when I try to add in my own transition I am met with a type issue.

The code for the transition:

```
<SnackbarProvider
          maxSnack={3}
          TransitionComponent={React.forwardRef(function Transition(
            props,
            ref
          ) {
            return <Slide direction="up" ref={ref} {...props} />
          })}
        >
```

Error shown when hovering over Slide:

```
Types of property 'children' are incompatible.
    Type 'ReactNode' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement<any, any> | undefined'.
      Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement<any, any> | undefined'.ts(2322)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply needed to change

`return <Slide direction="up" ref={ref} {...props} />`

to

`<Slide ref={ref} {...(props as SlideProps)} />`

Comment: Hey, What is SlideProps?

Comment: Props for Slide animation from mui